# add new item CRUD react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am practicing a little react, and I wanted to do a CRUD, the problem I have is when adding a new element.
I get the new data to reach the function that is in the parent called createNewItem (there I have a console.log), but I can not see is a new item reflected in the list and also added to the second click on the "save" button , not the first. What am I failing? Thanks for your help. I leave a sandbox with the code.

https://codesandbox.io/embed/wizardly-archimedes-x8jzn

Comment: I tried to put my answer in the comments because I do not think it is an "amazing" solution but it will work.

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the best way to handle this but I added this above your `createNewItem` in your `App/index.js`

```
  shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState){
    if (this.state.restoOriginales !== nextState.restoOriginales){
      console.log("NUEVO ITEM", nextState.restoOriginales);
      //put your setState code here with nextState.restoOriginales
    }
    return true;
  }
```

React documentation says

```
shouldComponentUpdate() is invoked before 
rendering when new props or state are being received. Defaults to true.
```

All this basically does is force the parent to be updated. To be honest there is probably a better way of handling this, but here is one solution that should work for you.

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that `setState` is async, so `console.log` won't show the new state straight away. To achieve that you need to use a callback for `setState`:

```
 createNewItem = event => {
    const newList = [event, ...this.state.restoOriginales];
    this.setState({ restoOriginales: newList }, () => { // Use callback here
      console.log("NUEVO ITEM", this.state.restoOriginales);
    });
  };
```

Also you'll need to redirect back to homepage or otherwise remove the form after an item is saved.

Comment: Thank you for help me. I we made some changes and now I cant see the new item, but not when I press Save btn. Only see when I go back whit the browser arrow.. why?